# win32: is there a WM sent to the child when parent window is destroyed, or orphans the child?

Tags: winapi, hwnd

I'm developing a plugin so I don't own the parent window, but it would help me workaround an issue if i can figure out when the parent window of my window is destroyed (or alternatively when it orphans my window).  Is this possible?  I was hoping my window might receive something like a WM_DETACH message, but i cant find such a message by googling.

Comment: Child windows are destroyed before the parent, so you get a `WM_DESTROY`.

Comment: A couple of good answers from our WinAPI "Experts" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23044113/10871073). Not that @Raymond isn't also one of our WinAPI Experts! :-)

Comment: Windows don't get orphaned. When a parent window is destroyed, its child windows are also destroyed. This is [documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroywindow): "*If the specified window is a parent or owner window, **DestroyWindow automatically destroys the associated child or owned windows** when it destroys the parent or owner window. The function first destroys child or owned windows, and then it destroys the parent or owner window.*"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Your child window always receives a WM_DESTROY message when its parent is getting destroyed.
From the MSDN [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-destroy#:%7E:text=This%20message%20is%20sent%20first%20to%20the%20window%20being%20destroyed%20and%20then%20to%20the%20child%20windows%20(if%20any)%20as%20they%20are%20destroyed):

*This message is sent first to the window being destroyed and* **then to the child windows** *(if any) as they are destroyed.*

So, obviously, there are 2 scenarios when your child window will get the WM_DESTROY message:

1. **You** destroy the window using DestroyWindow() function
2. **Parent** is getting destroyed, thus sending WM_DESTROY to all its children

Since there is no way to tell which one caused WM_DESTROY to being sent, you could add a `boolean IdestroyTheChild` variable and set it to true when **you** destroy your child. Then in WM_DESTROY message you simply check that boolean and do whatever you need to do.